# How to use NSStandardKeyBindingResponding with skhd?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) to configure custom keybindings in Mac OS.

I also want to (re)define some key behavior, like the `Home` and `End` keys from my external keyboard, by calling methods from [NSStandardKeyBindingResponding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding)

I can do it by creating a file at `~/Library/KeyBindings` (source: https://damieng.com/blog/2015/04/24/make-home-end-keys-behave-like-windows-on-mac-os-x/), but I would prefer to keep all keybindings into a single place.

I tried something like:

```rc
# Use windows/linux style keyboard
home : moveToBeginningOfParagraph:
end : moveToEndOfParagraph:
```

...but that didn't work. Since `skhd` calls commands using shell, I suppose it is possible by calling the methods through some Mac command, but I have no idea which and the docs don't provide examples for something like this.